# Name for first letter of a sentence and the first letter of a word

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the first letter of a sentence (`i` in this sentence)?

Is there a word for the first letter of each word in a sentence (`itawftfloewias` in this case)?

I understand that as terms, this could be described as an acrostic for the former, and an acrostic, acronym or an initialism for the latter case, but I'm wondering if this can describe the letters themselves, or just the subsequent output. **edit:** Please note that this is not the answer, just a suggestion, and it isn't correct use of these terms

My best guess would be initial for the latter, but I have no idea for the former - maybe acrostic would be a good choice

Comment: You said, 'I'm wondering if this does describe the letters themselves, or the subsequent output.' This can be easily checked in a dictionary—better do that, or your question might be closed for not satisfying the research requirement.

Comment: Having said that, I would be very surprised if there were single words with the meaning you require. But it is hard to prove a negative, of course.

Comment: @linguisticturn I've edited the question to clear up what I meant there. I understand that it describes the output only, or I would've already answered the question! :p

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you are asking if *acrostic, acronym,* or *initialism* can describe the letters themselves rather than the subsequent output. Isn't that question settled by the dictionary definitions of these words?

Comment: One thought: while *initial* does not by default describe the first letter of anything except  names (and also the large letter beginning a text or a division or paragraph), I **think** it would be OK to say, somewhere in your text, 'I am going to use the term *the sentence initial* to refer to the first letter of a sentence, and *the initials of the sentence* to refer to the first letters of the words in a sentence.'

Comment: @linguisticturn The question is a single world request to describe the first letter of a sentence and the first letter of a word. Those are my attempts, they're not questions

Comment: In that case, please rephrase, because the way you have it written now (*but I'm wondering if this can describe the letters themselves, or just the subsequent output*), it sounds as if *this* may refer to one of *acrostic, acronym,* or *initialism.* One possibility: *…but I'm **wondering if there are words that** can describe the letters themselves, not the subsequent output.*

Comment: I can do if it's matters, but I'm not sure what you're suggesting is what I meant to say. My suggestion was that I was wondering if those words could be used. Thanks for clearing up that they don't, but I think editing the question might remove information that's useful for others who may have thought the same as my suggestions, although I understand this is information also available in the dictionary, for those of us not as linguistically intelligence with English it's hard to understand the distinction, even after reading those definitions. Doesn't the title make the question clear anyways?

Comment: It always helps to make the question as clear as possible. Since you now know that *acrostic, acronym,* and *initialism* can't be used (at least not just as they are; see my comment above for a workaround), it's a good idea to edit the question to make it clear you know that they can't be used, so that newcomers to this question don't think you are asking about that.

Comment: Good stuff! I've added that edit to make it clear, and added your answer too (as you've rightly suggested, there doesn't seem to be a one-word answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EL&U prefers to have answers as answers rather than have them buried in the comments, I will here repeat a suggestion I made in the comments that the OP liked.

While *initial* does not by default describe the first letter of anything except names (and also the large letter beginning a text or a division or paragraph), I think it would be OK to say, somewhere in your text, 'I am going to use the term ***the sentence initial*** to refer to the first letter of a sentence, and ***the initials of the sentence*** to refer to the first letters of the words in a sentence.'

There are many variations on this general theme possible, e.g. ***word initial***, as the OP themself suggested in a comment.

Comment: But answers on ELU are meant to be recognised usages. These are merely free combinations (cf 'grey radiator'), not even collocations.  The first tranche of results for "the sentence initial" in a Google search are all for the compound premodifier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In general, yes. If you think this should be migrated, I have no objections. Having said that, I think this sort of question *might* be on-topic: is there a way to make a syntactic construction that can be temporarily defined to have a certain meaning, **and which native speakers would find natural?** It's this last part that (maybe) makes this on-topic.

Comment: OP asks specifically for a single word. If workarounds of such simple construction are allowed (on any site), we or they will be getting questions like 'What's a more concise way to say 'gloves one uses for gardening'?" (and _gardening gloves_ thankfully doesn't seem to be listed in major dictionaries, in spite of being far more cohesive than '[a] sentence initial').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They might allowed, I guess, only if 1. there do not appear to be any single words, and 2. the suggested workaround is not obvious. The threshold for 2. could be very low on ELL, and of course much higher here.

Answer (score 1):

[Initial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial) is actually also used for the first case, especially when referring to elaborated letters in historical books, like this capital O:

[image: Conversation-saints 01.jpg]
from Princeton, Public Domain, [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=504059)

Comment: Right—but that's only for the first letter of a **paragraph** or some larger division of text, not for individual sentences.

Comment: Also worth noting that *littera notabilior* is also sometimes used to refer to sentence initialisms or any capitalization in a text.

Comment: It seems like whilst not technically correct nor one word, most would readily understand "sentence initial" and "word initial"

Comment: @NickBull Yes, as I suggested in a comment above (the one starting with 'One thought…').

Comment: Sure thing! I've added 'word initial' too in my comment, which seems a little clearer to me. I figured since this is an answer regarding the use of the word initials, I'd add the comment here. Thanks linguisticturn